HTML Geolocation API does not work properly on some iOS devices
I created a PWA that requires access to users' geolocation to perform a certain action in the system. The correct operation would be the user opens the application, and then the operating system prompts them to allow sharing their exact location with the PWA. However, this is not happening with a few users who have iPhone 11 or XR.
I tested it on iPhones 14, 13, 11 Pro, and even iPhone 6, and it works as expected. I directly spoke with a user who was experiencing the problem and conducted some tests.
I checked if location access was allowed in the settings.
I verified if Safari was accepting with the option to always ask selected.
In the settings of my system's website, I checked if location access was allowed with the option to always ask chosen.
We changed all prompting options to allow.
We opened the following site https://whatpwacando.today/ and found that geolocation was also not possible.
Everything indicates that the issue lies with these users' phones; however, other geolocation methods work fine, as other geolocation apps function properly. This leads me to think that it might be a problem with Safari not working properly with the HTML Geolocation API.
I'm not sure if there are any more advanced settings that could help or if anyone else has encountered this issue.
The code:
 const locate = useCallback(() => {
  if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
    watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
      (position) => {
        if (position.coords.accuracy < 50) {
          // Visual feedback for accuracy state
          if (position.coords.accuracy <= 25) setCoordVariant("primary");
          else setCoordVariant("warning");

          // Clear coordinates after 5 minutes (Prevent storing coordinates for more than 5 minutes)
          setTimeout(() => {
            setCoordinates({ lat: null, lon: null });
            setAccuracy(null);
          }, 5 * 60 * 1000);

          // Stop locating
          setLocating(false);
          navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchId);
        }

        // Update coordinates
        const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
        setCoordinates({ lat: latitude, lon: longitude });
        setAccuracy(position.coords.accuracy);
      },
      handleGpsError,
      { enableHighAccuracy: true }
    );
  } else {
    alert("The browser does not support geolocation.");
  }
}, [alert, handleGpsError]);


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

As I said, it's not the code that's the issue, but rather the iPhones of these people. As I mentioned above, I tested on the same iPhone a website that is not made by me and that uses the HTML Geolocation API (https://whatpwacando.today/) and even with all the settings on the phone indicating that geolocation was accepted on that site, it appeared as if it were not allowed by the device. Anyway, there's the code snippet where I call the API (remembering that it works on all iPhones up to those before the 11 and XR)
